# Making the camel happy in camel case conversion

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written the function for camel-casing strings (the requirement is to kick-up the characters in the beginning of a word and after each hyphen, which is targeting personal names).

```
function sadCamelize(input) {
  return input.toLowerCase().replace(/([-\s])(.)/g,
    function(match, separator, starter) {
      return separator + starter.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Now, I'd like to make my camel happy so that even the first character of the string (not succeeding space nor hyphen), will be kicked-up. Id est, instead of:

> HONKA-HONKA   ->   honka-Honka

I'd like to get

> HONKA-HONKA   ->   Honka-Honka

At the moment I'm stuck, probably due to annoyance. All camels are depressed and so an I. Also - what is the correct nomenclature of what I call sad/happy camel (the head down/up)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function happyCamelize(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z])([a-z]+)/gi, function(_, $1, $2) {
        // _: The entire matched string. not used here.
        // $1: The first group. The first alphabet.
        // $2: The second group. The rest alphabets.
        return $1.toUpperCase() + $2.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Example:

```
happyCamelize('HONKA-HONKA') // "Honka-Honka"
```

**NOTE** This code will not change single length word.

```
happyCamelize('h') // => "h"
happyCamelize('H') // => "H"
```

If you want to also camelize single length word, use `/([a-z])([a-z]*)/gi`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works but shouldn't it fail on capital characters? How does the regex know to match "A-Z" as well?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, using `i` flag mean ignore case; `A-Z` match uppercase, lowercase alphabet both.

Comment: @falsetru Missed the "i". Now I see it. I was starting to suspect black sorcery (which regex in most cases feels like, anyway, hihi).

Answer (score 4):

This ugly one liner does the job.

```
"HONKA-HONKA".toLowerCase().split(/\b/g).map(function(word) { return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)}).join('')
```

Let me explode it:

```
"HONKA-HONKA".toLowerCase().split(/\b/g).map(function(word) {
  return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
}).join('');
```

Now wrap into a function

```
function sadCamelize(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(/\b/g).map(function(word) {
      return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }).join('');
}
```

**Here's the sequence of actions:**

- convert everything to lowercase
- split by word [(\b)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)
- map each portion of regex result so that the first letter becomes
  uppercase
- word.slice(1) removes the first element from the array

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for a mdn reference, however a comment or edit would be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question has been answered by lukas below, so I will answer the second part.

> honkaHonka = camelCase
>
> HonkaHonka = PascalCase

There are other variations and synonyms as well. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms

Comment: or Dromedary case or UpperCamelCase

Comment: @mplungjan BumpyCaps or CamelCaps or HumpBack or InterCaps or WikiCase  : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms